# hava regex starts with and ends with and skipping a specific charachter

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I would like to find a string that starts and ends with a specific special character but skipping when another specific charachter.

I want to find any string that starts with "hello"and ends with a dot "." but not like "here end." this must be skipped when "here end" is preceding the dot ".".

Sample :

```
String para = "XXXX@gxxl.com. this will share the costs and hello you  the initial here end. must be carrefully done.Keep going."
```

I tried the following regex but its not working:

```
hello.+?((?=([.]))
```

I got this :

```
"hello you  the initial here end."
```

but this is required :

```
"hello you  the initial here end. must be carrefully done."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can yse

```
hello.*?(?<!here end)\.
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GTXtFB/1). *Details*:

- `hello` - a fixed string
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?<!here end)\.` - a `.` that is not immediately preceded with `here end`.

If you need to exclude the `.` from match, put it into a lookaround, `hello.*?(?<!here end)(?=\.)`.